# How can I automate urls for django generic views?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

I have subclassed Django's generic views for my project. I use them extensively to create basic CRUD views on our front-end site. Some models have just a create view, some have a read and update, etc.

This works well but I still write a line of code for each URL. ie:

> ```
> url(r'^referrer/create/$',ReferrerCreateView.as_view(), name='referrer_create'),
> url(r'^referrer/$',ReferrerListView.as_view(), name='referrer_list'),
> url(r'^referrer/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$',ReferrerUpdateView.as_view(),
> ```
>
> name='referrer_update'),

I then do this for every model and the views that model has. This doesn't seem to be a very DRY approach to me. Is there a good approach to automating these urls for any generic view that has been created for a model?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a method that will return a list of `url()` calls given a set of views. Something like

```
views = {
    'base_name': 'referrer',
    'create_view': ReferrerCreateView,
    'list_view': ReferrerListView,
    'update_view': ReferrerUpdateView,
}

def generate_urls(views):
    return [
        url(r'^%s/create/$' % views['base_name'], views['create_view'].as_view(), '%s_create' % views['base_name'],
        # and so on
    ]
```

Then you just need to do

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', *generate_urls(views))
```

For every set of views you have.

That being said I believe **you shouldn't do this**. This solution (or any different implementations) is over complicated and will add an extra layer you'll need to go through if things go wrong.

There's nothing wrong of having some boilerplate code, especially configuration code, because it makes your life much easier to debug in the future.

Comment: This is beautiful! I have never thought about doing something like this but it looks like a great way to do api generations and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same very concern and I shared it here before
One answer was the use of django rest framework as it implements such url patterns on its own!?! I didn't experience this solution yet.

My workaround is to have a dedicated file for crud operations for every model.
By that solution I decreased the matching time , and grouped related model pattern in one file.
BUT I understand that wont fully solve your question